# GQL doesnt automatically invoke query

Tags: reactjs, react-router, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have two components as below

**SongList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class SongList extends Component {
  renderSongs() {
    return this.props.data.songs.map(song => {
      return (
        <li key={song.id} className="collection-item">
          {song.title}
        </li>
      );
    });
  }
  render() {
    if (this.props.data.loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <ul className="collection">
          {this.renderSongs()}
        </ul>
        <Link 
          to="/songs/new"
          className="btn-floating btn-large red right"
        >
          <i className="material-icons">add</i>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const query = gql`
  {
    songs {
      id,
      title
    }
  }
`;

export default graphql(query)(SongList);
```

**SongCreate.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { Link, hashHistory } from 'react-router';

class SongCreate extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { title: '' }
  }

  onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.props.mutate({
      variables: {
        title: this.state.title
      }
    }).then(() => hashHistory.push('/'));
    // .catch((err) => console.log('DEBUG::err', err));

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link to="/">
          Back
        </Link>
        <h3>Create a New Song</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <label>Song Title: </label>
          <input 
            onChange={event => this.setState({ title: event.target.value })}
            value={this.state.title}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mutation = gql`
  mutation AddSong($title: String){
    addSong(title: $title) {
      title
    }
  }
`;

export default graphql(mutation)(SongCreate);
```

Basically the situation I'm facing is, in `SongCreate` component, once successfully mutate the `addSong` method, it will navigate back to `SongList`, however, I don't see the new song on `SongList`, and in order for me to see that, I have to refresh the page. It seems to me that the query at `SongList` doesnt get invoked?

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the same fields on the mutation results and the query results. That way, the internal cache of apollo will be updated accordingly ([see doc section](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#automatic-updates))

```
const mutation = gql`
  mutation AddSong($title: String){
    addSong(title: $title) {
      id         <==== Added this to match the query 
      title
    }
  }
`;
```

I also suggest that you play around with [the chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apollo-client-developer-t/jdkknkkbebbapilgoeccciglkfbmbnfm) to view the apollo cache

Comment: I've tested your way but unfortunately it's not working. And if `apollo` restricting us to add `id` field, wouldn't it sounds like defeating the best selling point of `graphql` which allows me to define the property freely?

Comment: This is due to the default caching behavior of apollo client, you may also configure `refetchQueries` or you may configure the song list query to avoid caching altogether. The way I suggested is not the only way but it's simple ^^

Comment: It's not working on my end however I'm guessing it's due to im using a rather outdated version where `apollo-client: "^0.8.1", "graphql": "^0.8.2"`. Will spend some time on the newer version and try out your suggestion. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that due to the reason the query been executed once, and when you add a new item and route back to the listing page, query will not rerun due to caching. So in order to fix that, we can refetch the query.
In `SongCreate` component, we can define `refetchQueries` within `mutate` as below:

```
this.props.mutate({
      variables: {
        title: this.state.title
      },
      refetchQueries: [{ query: gql`.........` }] //<======
    }).then(() => hashHistory.push('/'));
```